# Pandas Boolean Indexing Issue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

Can anyone explain the following behaviour. I am expecting all three rows to be returned.

```
import pandas as pd

test_dict = {
    'col1':[None, None, None],
    'col2':[True, False, True],
    'col3':[True, True, False]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(test_dict)

df[ df.col1 | df.col2 | df.col3 ]
>>> Return only first two rows (index 0 and 1)
```

Replacing the `None` values with empty strings using `df.fillna('')` appears to fix it but I don't understand why the first two rows work fine if `None` is an issue.

Also changing the order of the comparisons effects it. If I swap `col2` and `col3` in the mask then the row with index 1 is no longer returned but the row with index 2 is returned. If `col1` comes last then all rows are returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the evaluation is from left to right. That is

```
df.col1 | df.col2 | df.col3 == (df.col1 | df.col2) | df.col3
```

Now, I think this is an implementation choice in Pandas that `None | True` is evaluated as `False`. So in this case `(df.col1 | df.col2)` is all `False`. That's why you only see the first to rows.

To fix this. use

```
df[df.any(axis=1)]
```